# throwing away tens & hundreds columns of an int in C

Tags: c, gcc

I want to test an integer value for its units column value only, I don't care about the tens or hundreds columns. The int value is a countdown timer

So when the units column is 0 to 4 I want the screen to display something, when the units is 5 to 9 I want the screen to display something else. I want to basically isolate the units column value

Can't think of a quick and dirty way of doing this without dividing by 100 and subtracting the number of 100s then doing the same with the number of 10s. Is there a simpler way of shifting and testing for 0 to 4 or 5 to 9 in the units column

So far I am trying:

```
int zero_count_units = a_zero_count - (((a_zero_count / 100) * 100) + ((a_zero_count / 10) * 10));

if( (zero_count_units >= 0) && (zero_count_units < 5) )     // 0-4 units column
{
}
else if( (zero_count_units >= 5) && (zero_count_units <= 9) )   // 5-9 units column
{
}
```

My brain isn't working particularly well this morning! Any advice appreciated
Many thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `unit column`???

Comment: How about the modulo operator, `%`?

Comment: By units column I mean the decimal units column, i.e units from 0-9 discounting 10s and 100s

Comment: SO far I am attempting the following:

int zero_count_units = a_zero_count - (((a_zero_count / 100) * 100) + ((a_zero_count / 10) * 10));
   
if( (a_zero_count >= 0) && (a_zero_count < 5) )

Comment: `val % 10` is typically transformed into a reciprocal integer 'division' by a constant, which eliminates the need for a slow, high latency divide instruction - if it exists. GCC will perform this optimization.

Comment: This has nothing to do with embedded systems development so I'll remove that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `%` ([modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) operator.

The expression `n % m` for two integers `n` and `m` evaluates to the remainder after `n` is divided by `m`.

In your case `m` would be 10, since you're interested in the remainder after division by ten:

```
const int zero_count_units = a_zero_count % 10;
```

Comment: Yes, of course! Modulo of 10 is all I need, no need to worry about the hundreds. Thanks

Comment: @user2431995 Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark, if you're happy with it.

Comment: It is better termed a remainder operator since it computes a remainder after division (negative when numerator is negative) rather than a unique designator of the modulo congruence class (would be same for `5%3` and `-1%3`).

Answer (score 0):

```
int yourNumber = 324687              /* whatever your number is */
int temp = yourNumber;
                                     /* i is to track which digit you're at */
for ( int i = 1; temp != 0; i++ ) {  /* ( temp != 0 ) is the same as ( temp ) alone */
    if ( i > 3 ) {
        if ( temp % 10 < 5 ) {       /* the current last digit of temp */
            /* display something */
        }
        else {
            /* display something else */
        }
    }
    temp /= 10;                      /* this cuts off the last digit */
}
```

I think this would do what you are trying to ask for. You said you don't want tens (`i == 2`), hundreds (`i == 3`), I assumed you wouldn't want ones (`i == 1`) as well, but you may play around with that as you wish.